# jquery Form Change Detection with exceptions

Tags: jquery, onchange

I have a function that detects if there has been a change to a form:

```
$('#CreditForm').on('change paste', 'input, select, textarea', function(){
    console.log('form changed');
});
```

But there is one set of radio buttons I do not want to include, so I need to do something like (syntax is not correct - shown as example of what I am trying to achieve:

```
$('#CreditForm').on('change paste', 'input, select, textarea').not('input[name="AppType"]') function(){
    console.log('form changed');
});
```

What would be the proper syntax to achieve this?

Comment: Why complicate it. The question is concerning the correct syntax for the code shown and the question is not dependent on the content of the form, but in the correct jQuery syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track. Just select inputs *except* that one in the first place.

```js
$('#CreditForm').on('change paste', 'input:not([name="AppType"]), select, textarea', 
  function(){
    console.log('form changed');
  }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" id="CreditForm">
  <input type="text" value="I trigger">
  <input type="text" name=AppType value="I do not">
  <select name="" id="">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
  </select>
  <textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
</form>
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks!